# python in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. Python3.6 disappeared and python3.8 was automatically installed. I am now having trouble using numpy and pandas with python3.8. Attempts to install them are met with a message that they are already installed. However, running python3.8 software that attempts to import them fails with a message that they are not there. I happen to still have a version of python 3.5, which works fine with numpy and pandas. How do I convince python 3.8 that numpy and pandas are really there? I have tried to uninstall numpy and pandas with pip3, thinking that I could fix everything by reinstalling them, but the uninstall command is met with a message that they are not there. I also happen to have a version of python 3.9, and it also has difficulty finding numpy and pandas. There is something strange with my installation of python3.8 and I would like to get it fixed. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Your question should show actual input and output demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Libraries are installed to paths specific to each version of Python - something installed in Python 3.5's path isn't going to be available for 3.8 or 3.9. You'll have to install numpy and pandas for 3.8 and 3.9 separately (e.g., `python3.8 -m pip install numpy pandas` or make a venv for each version and `pip install` in those venvs).

Comment: Remove python packages from /usr/local/...  Then you have to use packages from official repositories - python3-numpy, python3-pandas  for best success. Please show exact errors in the question body.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to install with `pip3`. The problem might be that `pip3` is installing for `python3.5`. I think you want it for `python3.8`. For installing a library, say `numpy` with `python3.8`, do this:

```
python3.8 -m pip install numpy
```

or if you want to install it for all your users

```
sudo python3.8 -m pip install numpy
```

This should do the trick.